# How to catch error and redirect: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

Tags: urls, error-handling

When attempting to access URLs such as `http://web.local/webpagehttp://web.local/webpage`, we encounter issues and this error appears in the log:

`A potentially dangerous Request. Path value was detected from the client (:)`

I am using **sitecore 9.0.1** and **asp.net**. Is there any way I can catch cases like this and redirect to 404?

Comment: need to redirect into custom error page like https://domainname/500

Comment: to handle issue and redirect to 404 or 500 check out this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/handling-500-errors-in-sitecore-9

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/handling-500-errors-in-sitecore-9